# Update the document in Elasticsearch with version number

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I update the document like that but I got VersionConflictEngineException.

```
const params: RequestParams.Update = {
  index,
  type,
  id,
  body: {
    doc: {
      ...esUpdateCommands
    }
  }
};

await this.client.update(params);
```

Then, I added one more step to update the document with the version number. Here is my code:

```
const params: RequestParams.Update = {
      index,
      type,
      id,
      body: {
        doc: {
          ...esUpdateCommands
        },
        script: `ctx._version = ${new_version}`
      }
    };
```

But I got `can't provide both script and doc;` error.

How can I update the doc with version number?

Comment: Please also state what elasticsearch versions are you using?
Since elasticsearch 6.x not more than two types are allowed 
(which is possible in ES 5.x)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a very old version which is 1.x.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I added retry_on_conflict: 4 field when updating the document. It's automatically handling the versioning when conflict occurs.